# how to verified firefox add-ons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

hello guys i try to learn more about how to create firefox add-ons 
by following this article
[Getting_Started_with_Firefox_Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Getting_Started_with_Firefox_Extensions)

but when i try to install the add-on 
firefox add-ons manger tell me this could not be verified to use in firefox

i read this [article](https://support.mozilla.org/1/firefox/40.0.3/WINNT/en-US/unsigned-addons) and try give me the same can any one tell me how to avoid this problem

Comment: "Only extensions signed with a digital certificate can verify authorship. Signed extensions are rare. Click on the Install Now button. After the extension is installed, you'll be asked to restart Firefox. Installing, uninstalling, enabling and disabling add-ons require a restart to complete, with the exception of NPAPI plugins, Add-ons SDK extensions and bootstrapped extensions. This is an important point to keep in mind if you're building an extension that manipulates other extensions or themes."

Comment: Go to about:config and search for pref `xpinstall.signatures.required` it is default at true, set it to false

Comment: the same problem" XUL School Hello World Could not be verified for use in firefox. proceed with caution"

Comment: @HishamElsayad can you link me to that page Ill get it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look into this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK the legacy SDK will go away at some point, so better start now using the latest SDK.

When doing that, you will use jpm (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29) With which you can test add-ons without installing them (jpm run)